# How to delete rows from a pandas DataFrame with method chaining?

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

Does pandas have an analogue to dplyr's filter() operation?
basically I'd like to be able to remove rows based on a predicate.

I can of course do `df = df[condition]`, but that doesn't compose as nicely as method chaining.

Comment: pandas has a [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas.DataFrame.filter) method but this takes a sequence of labels, generally one would use the predicate to make a mask and pass this

Answer (score 3):

use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(-5, 6, (10, 10)),
    columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

df

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
0  0  4 -1  1 -3 -1 -4 -5 -1  2
1 -4  2 -1  0  5 -1  1 -3  1  4
2  3 -2  3 -2 -4  5  1  1  0 -2
3  1  4 -5  4 -3 -3 -3 -3 -4  4
4 -3  4  4  5 -2 -3 -1  3  3 -1
5  0  0 -1 -1  2  2  5 -4 -1 -1
6 -2  1  2  0 -1 -1  1  0  4 -4
7  5  2  5  2  3  2  3 -3  1  1
8 -2 -5  1  4  0 -1  4  4 -5  3
9 -3 -2 -5  0 -5 -2 -2  2  0 -1
```

You can easily pipeline operations based on filtering conditions

```
df.query('A < 0')

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1 -4  2 -1  0  5 -1  1 -3  1  4
4 -3  4  4  5 -2 -3 -1  3  3 -1
6 -2  1  2  0 -1 -1  1  0  4 -4
8 -2 -5  1  4  0 -1  4  4 -5  3
9 -3 -2 -5  0 -5 -2 -2  2  0 -1
```

You can include multiple conditions

```
df.query('A < 0 & B < -1')

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
8 -2 -5  1  4  0 -1  4  4 -5  3
9 -3 -2 -5  0 -5 -2 -2  2  0 -1
```

You can do many cool things

```
df.query('-3 < A < 3 & H * J > 0')

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
5  0  0 -1 -1  2  2  5 -4 -1 -1
8 -2 -5  1  4  0 -1  4  4 -5  3
```

And it all gets returned as a dataframe to enable the next operation

Comment: does this work with predicates on non-numeric columns?

Comment: Yes, if you provide sample data and what you'd like to do with it.  We can show you how to do it.

Comment: What if I want to pass a more complicated function or I don't want to code through a string like that?  Is there another option?